# Deploy X509 certificates to Blackberry OS using BB Fusion MDM

Tags: blackberry, x509certificate, mdm

I have been googling for a while but have not found an answer to my question.

Is it possible to deploy a self-signed CA X509 certificate to a Blackberry device using a MDM solution? It must be possible over-the-air.

Can anyone give me a hint or further links on this topic?

Thanks in advance!